# Contract testing messages in a Flux in Spring Cloud Stream gives IllegalArgumentException Message must not be null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-contract

I'm trying to contract test a Flux of events emitted from an endpoint using Spring Cloud Stream and Spring Cloud Contract. However, I'm getting an `IllegalArgumentException` with detailMessage `Message must not be null` when running my test. Or in other words I'm not receiving any messages on my message receiver. My spring cloud version is Hoxton. I've added the following dependencies in my pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--TEST -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <classifier>test-binder</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

I've configured a new binding following the samples [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/source-samples). Is working properly when I run the app and I send a `curl -X POST localhost:8080` request.

application.properties

```
stubrunner.stream.enabled=true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.uppercase-in-0.destination=test
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.uppercase-in-0.group=testGroup
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.uppercase-out-0.destination=hood
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consume-in-0.destination=hood
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consume-out-0.destination=downtown
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.supplier-out-0.destination=test
spring.cloud.function.definition=uppercase;consume;supplier
```

Controller

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/")
 public void handlePost() {
    Faker faker = new Faker();
    Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(faker.chuckNorris().fact()).build();
    //    supplier.get();
    EventSupplier.processor.onNext(message);
 }
```

Bean definition

```
@Configuration
public class EventSupplier {
  public static final EmitterProcessor<Message<String>> processor = EmitterProcessor.create();

  @Bean
  //  public Supplier<String> supplier() {
  public Supplier<Flux<Message<String>>> supplier() {
    //    return () -> "";
    return () -> processor;
  }

}
```

Contracts Base test

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMessageVerifier
@EnableBinding(KafkaStreamerApplication.class)
public abstract class KafkaStreamerApplicationTests {

  @Autowired
  private DummyController dummyController;

  public void supply() {
     dummyController.handlePost();
  }
}
```

Contract

```
org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract.make {
  label 'some_label'
  input {
   triggeredBy("supply()")
  }
  outputMessage {
    sentTo('supplier-out-0')
    body(
            anyNonBlankString()
            )
    headers {
        messagingContentType(applicationJson())
    }
  }
 }
```

I've tried creating contracts for function and consumer and both worked. I've also tried using a supplier of type `String` instead of `Flux<Message<String>>` and worked too. You can look at the commented lines at the code above.

While debugging I've seen that in `StreamMessageCollectorMessageReceiver` I'm getting a `DirectWithAttributesChannel` instance when retrieving the `MessageChannel` bean at `receive("supplier-out-0", 5, "SECONDS")` method. Also while looking into the documentation I've found a  `MessageChannel` implementation that, to me, looks like a candidate to be the one should have been instantiated [`FluxMessageChannel`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/channel/FluxMessageChannel.html).

My guess is that spring cloud contract is waiting for a message to be sent into the queue directly(`DirectWithAttributesChannel`) but since the flux is already in the queue and I'm just updating the flux content, it means that not message is pushed into the queue(`FluxMessageChannel`?) so no message is received(`null`) and that's why I'm getting an `IllegalArgumentException` with details `Message must not be null` error when running my tests.

**Is there something missing in my configuration? Can this scenario be tested by contracts? Is a bad approach to test this by using contracts?**

Comment: I see `@EnableBinding` annotation which I assume defines some channels etc. . . The point is that it is mutually exclusive you can either use functional or annotation based binding model and by having EnableBinding you effectively disabled the functional one. Consider using [this sample](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_suppliers_sources) (which shows a complete app) as a starting point.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky thank you so much for the link, I was missing de `@PollableBean` annotation instead of `@Bean`. So I guess my supplier was not being polled. I think there are few concepts I might have not understood properly yet and I got confused with the samples I was looking at. Anyway, if you want to write your comment as an answer I'll mark it as the valid one.

Comment: No, your miss-configuration has nothing to do with PollableBean. As I stated, the EnableBinding disables functional configuration all together.

Comment: Mmm that's curious, I could not make the contract test pass until I annotated my bean as `@PollableBean`. Anyway, I removed the `@EnableBinding` since it was not required. I'd like to add that all implementations have worked on running the application but fail when using Spring Cloud Contract. That's  what I do not understand  at all yet why it is happening.

Comment: I don't see your entire app to pass any judgement, so perhaps you can push it somewhere so we can take a look

Comment: This is the url of the repo with my code https://github.com/brjt23/kafka-streamer

Comment: Your project doesn't compile. EventConsumer can't find 'getValue' method on CloudEventImpl and there are errors in the actual application. Please make sure such sample project compiles and also has just enough to reproduce the error

Comment: Sorry but I don't know why is not compiling. I can make it run locally. I've run it in my machine and in my brother's laptop(clean installation with java se 13, mvn, and git). Also asked some workmates to test it. I've updated the repo removing unnecessary code. When doing a `mvn clean package` you should get the IllegalArgumentException. If you cannot run it let me know and I'll test it with docker.

Comment: @BorjaBodoque did you end up finding the root cause? I have the same issue.

Comment: Hi @RodMcCutcheon I did not. The only way I could make it pass the test was making it a `PollableBean` rather than a `Bean` and at some point I've stopped looking for the root cause. At [this](https://github.com/brjt23/kafka-streamer) repository I published an example that also contains the workaround in a commented line at `src/main/java/com/example/streams/kafkastreamer/config/EventSupplier.java`.  If you find something I'll be happy to hear.